# Sapi and javascript

Tags: javascript, sapi

I am searching the web about how can I use SAPI speech recognition through javascript. To be more specific I want to create a web application that will work on local server (may not have internet access) that will convert text to speech.

I have found some examples [Link 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sapi5.beta/qE1DdYxE1H0), [Link 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a3613ac2-e347-42ff-a4f7-4f8693b9d6dc/sapi-with-javascript) but none of them worked. Is there any workable example about this? Is there any other way to do this in a web application (without the need of internet connection)?

Answer (score 0):

SAPI objects are "not safe for scripting", and while you *can* use SAPI from javascript, you have to turn off a lot of security settings, as well as putting the web host into the trusted sites zone.  I've done this for a demo, but it's nothing I'd care to allow outside the confines of my own laptop.

Alternatively, Windows 8.1 has javascript TTS bindings through the [Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx) namespace.

Another option would be to build an [HTML Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); this environment allows unrestricted access to all ActiveX objects.

Comment: This is a good solution for windows 8 users but it doent's solve the problem for other Winows versions. I was wanter if there is any other solution for local use.

Comment: @JimPapas Updated answer to talk about HTML applications, which disable scripting checks.