# HTML-Text to Speech not working in Windows 7

Tags: html, text-to-speech

Created code for Text to Speech application, but nothing happens. What is wrong with it? I am using Windows 7.

```
<html>
<head>
    <body>

    Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
                <button id="Speak">Speak</button>

        <button id="SaveAudio">Save Audio to File</button>
              <textarea id="Data" style="height: 100%; width: 75%; font-size: 22pt" name="Data">
    </textarea>
    <textarea id="TextStatus" style="width: 20%; height: 20%;font-size: 16pt; border:none"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice") what is this ? javascript?

Comment: Build in function text to speech....

Answer (score 0):

`Set sapi = CreateObject("Sapi.SpVoice"); will fail, as SAPI objects aren't safe for scripting. See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532236/175201) to see some alternatives.